How to extend the Akeneo Product with a further property?
TL;DR
I got a custom Akeneo PIM bundle and want to add a new column "stock" to the product grid and onto the detail product page in the Akeneo backend. It's a new property and a new column. So I added a column stock to the table pim_catalog_product and a property stock to the Entity\Product class. The latter was not done directly of course: I created a custom Product entity in my bundle and extended it from the original Akeneo Product. But that isn't working correctly. The mapping and / or the query builder is wrong.
Issues / Errors
I'm getting the following errors:

When I try to validate the schema, I get the error The table with name 'akeneo_pim.pim_catalog_product' already exists.

$ docker compose exec fpm bin/console doctrine:schema:validate
Mapping
-------
[OK] The mapping files are correct.
Database
--------
17:11:51 CRITICAL  [console] Error thrown while running command "doctrine:schema:validate". Message: "The table with name 'akeneo_pim.pim_catalog_product' already exists." ["exception" => Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException^ { …},"command" => "doctrine:schema:validate","message" => "The table with name 'akeneo_pim.pim_catalog_product' already exists."]
In SchemaException.php line 108:
The table with name 'akeneo_pim.pim_catalog_product' already exists.


When I try to retrieve a product by opening its detail page in the Akeneo PIM backend, I get the error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.id' in 'where clause'.

$ tail -f ./var/logs/dev.log
...
request.CRITICAL:
Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\InvalidFieldNameException:
"An exception occurred while executing 
    'SELECT 
        t1.id AS id_2, 
        t1.is_enabled AS is_enabled_3, 
        t1.identifier AS identifier_4, 
        t1.raw_values AS raw_values_5, 
        t1.created AS created_6, 
        t1.updated AS updated_7, 
        t1.quantified_associations AS quantified_associations_8, 
        t1.stock AS stock_9, 
        t1.family_id AS family_id_10, 
        t1.product_model_id AS product_model_id_11, 
        t1.family_variant_id AS family_variant_id_12 
     FROM pim_catalog_product t1 
     WHERE t0.id = ?' 
with params ["1207"]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.id' in 'where clause'"
at /srv/pim/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 60

{"exception":
    "[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\InvalidFieldNameException(code: 0):
        An exception occurred while executing 
            'SELECT 
                t1.id AS id_2, 
                t1.is_enabled AS is_enabled_3, 
                t1.identifier AS identifier_4, 
                t1.raw_values AS raw_values_5, 
                t1.created AS created_6, 
                t1.updated AS updated_7, 
                t1.quantified_associations AS quantified_associations_8, 
                t1.stock AS stock_9, 
                t1.family_id AS family_id_10, 
                t1.product_model_id AS product_model_id_11, 
                t1.family_variant_id AS family_variant_id_12 
            FROM pim_catalog_product t1 
            WHERE t0.id = ?' 
        with params [\"1207\"]:

    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.id' in 'where clause' 
    at /srv/pim/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:60, 
    Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 42S22):
    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.id' in 'where clause' 
    at /srv/pim/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:123,
    PDOException(code: 42S22):
    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.id' in 'where clause'
    at /srv/pim/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:121)"
} []

Code
src/Tpg/Bundle/AkeneoTpgBundle/Entity/Product.php
<?php
namespace Tpg\Bundle\AkeneoTpgBundle\Entity;

use Akeneo\Pim\Enrichment\Component\Product\Model\Product as AkeneoProduct;

class Product extends AkeneoProduct
{
    private $stock;

    public function getStock(): ?int
    {
        return $this->stock;
    }

    public function setStock(?int $stock): self
    {
        $this->stock = $stock;

        return $this;
    }
}

config/services/services.yml
parameters:
  pim_catalog.entity.product.class: 'Tpg\Bundle\AkeneoTpgBundle\Entity\Product'

src/Tpg/Bundle/AkeneoTpgBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Product.orm.yml
Tpg\Bundle\AkeneoTpgBundle\Entity\Product:
  type: entity
  table: pim_catalog_product
  fields:
    stock:
      type: integer
      nullable: false

Migration
// a trivial migration class

Some more context
I'm developing an Akeneo PIM bundle for displaying the product stock (the number of available items) on the product
list and the single product page. The stock is supposed to be retrieved from another system via a REST
API (triggered by a cronjob & a Symfony command).
Some technical details:

Akeneo Community Standard Edition 5 (akeneo/pim-community-dev v5.0.120)
Symfony 4.4
Doctrine 2 (doctrine/dbal v2.10.0)
Doctrine Migrations 1 (doctrine/migrations v1.8.1)
PHP 7.4
Docker
Bundle: Currently in the src/ directory of the Akeneo PIM project in the Tpg\Bundle\AkeneoTpgBundle namespace.
Later supposed to be extracted to a separate repository and added via Composer.

I haven't found any appropriate documentation to this topic or to "How to develop a custom Akeneo PIM bundle".

You should look into Inheritence Mapping to better get an idea of how Doctrine deals with inheritance. If you're not able to mark the superclass appropriately, then consider using a table join instead.
